# mediaelement.js - Subtitles are not visible on iPad or Safari(fullscreen only)

Tags: html5-video, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to use subtitles with MediaElement.js HTML5 video player (the same behavior is with  VideoJS). The subtitles are not displayed on iPad2 (4.3.3) at all and are not displayed in Safari 5.0.5 (OSX 10.6) player fullscreen mode. I'm using [mediaelements.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) front page for testing.

Is this technical limitation or bug in the libraries?

Thanks,
Radim